# Pronunciation of "gucken"

Tags: pronunciation

I've heard the `g` in `gucken` pronounced more like a `k`, but in the [Duden dictionary](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gucken) I see no indication that it's pronounced that way. Do most Germans actually pronounce the word with a `k`, or is it just for some parts of the country?

Comment: To me it sounds rather awkward to hear it pronounced with an /ɡ/ as in dog or god.

Comment: After chirlus explanation I found out what else the Duden has to say: [kucken](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kucken)

Comment: There is also a second, independant trend: to pronounce the `ck` like `g/gg`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a bit confusing. Originally, the verb is *gucken*, pronounced with a *g* as is to be expected from the spelling. However, in northern German dialects, there is an unrelated verb *kieken* with about the same meaning (to look), giving rise to a hybrid *kucken*. This, in turn, has expanded quite a bit southward, even into regions where *kieken* is completely absent (and probably not even understood).

As *kucken* is highly colloquial, some people prefer to write *gucken* instead, while continuing to say *kucken*.

Comment: The link I added was a reference to support your statement that *kucken* may have evolved from Low German *kieken*. Here it is again for people who are interested: http://www.dwds.de/?qu=gucken&submit_button=Suche&view=1 (it is not broken here).

Answer (score 3):

### [gucken](http://de.thefreedictionary.com/gucken)

There are two regionally different variants of pronunciation, ['gʊkn], and [ˈgʊkən] mostly used in the southern parts of Germany.

In the region where I live (Swabia) people tend to pronounce this verb somehow like [ˈkʊken̩] when they want to speak or try to sound like speaking *"Hochdeutsch"* imitating the northern variant [kucken](http://de.thefreedictionary.com/kucken).

Note that the sound sample from the "Aussprachedatenbank der ARD" linked in the [Duden entry](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=gucken&submit_button=Suche&view=1) also pronounce it with [g].

Comment: Even here in northern germany, we write it as "gucken" but pronounce it like "kucken". If I remember right, the spelling "kucken" was added to the Duden about 20 or 30 years ago - noone I know uses it and it is seen as a bad spelling by most.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have never known anybody in the Southwest to pronounce "gucken" as "kucken".

Comment: because they usually pronounce the "ck" as "gg" as in the top-level comment by Tosho. In the south, there are a couple dialects that soften these consonants. This is still not represented in spelling! They'd write it as 'gucken', but they say ['gʊgn].

Answer (score 1):

In my native Augsburg Swabian (Augschburger​Schwäbisch) dialect, we pronounce 'gucken' with a g. Example: Was gugsch'n so blehd? (standard German: Warum guckst du so blöd? - g is pronounced like k). English: Why are you gawking so stupidly?