German word for listening or similar that sounds like "Kuchen"
I've been listening to a podcast, and they seem to use a word that sounds like "Kuchen" or "kochen" to mean listening to something. Context is for example that one person could talk about a podcast they have listened to (very meta, I know). I guess it could be that the word means something more general than listening, along the lines of "enjoyed" or "checked out" or something like that.
I've obviously tried looking it up in the dictionary, but all I find is cake and cooking.
Update:
Turns out I misremembered the context, and it was actually about watching rather than listening.
As requested in the comments, here is an example from the podcast:
https://www.easygerman.org/podcast/episodes/523
The relevant sentence starts at about 8:20 or so, and actually it turns out this episode is on youtube, with German subtitles, where it says "dass wir so viele [...] Filme und Serien geguckt haben". Direct link: https://youtu.be/2d7pzRIK0RM?si=bSx7kR1YHZCnnxZT&t=502

Maybe horchen? In some Regions the ch in horchen is pronounced like in Kuchen.

Olafant's suggestion seems to be the only one that makes sense, although "Ich horche einem Podcast" seems to be dialectal or at least joking.

Maybe kucken (to watch), if you have trouble telling "ch" and "k" apart. This is for visual media and not for podcasts, though

Kucken is probably the right answer, I guess I must have misunderstood and/or misremembered the context and they were actually talking about a video. I'll try to go back and check. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Also, the link was super useful. Kucken isn't in my dictionary, but gucken is, and wiktionary gives some context: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gucken#German

@Tor, also see https://german.stackexchange.com/q/8007/3237

@Dodezv - I was thinking kucken/gucken too but I couldn't reconcile that with an audio medium. Both "gucken" and "kucken" are listed in Wiktionary, given as different spellings of the same word, and they say it's usually pronounced "kucken" no matter how it's spelled. I gather it's one of those informal words that's spoken a lot more than it's written. A variation is "Guck-guck", which I've heard as German approximation of "Peek-a-boo".

@RDBury: I have never come across "Guck-guck", and I am pretty sure it is usually spelt (and pronounced) "Kuckuck", just like the bord (cuckoo).

O. R. Mapper - Maybe it's regional, and I assume there's no standard spelling. I first saw it in the Netflix series "The Hollow" (Season 1; ep. 3).  I also found this kid's YouTube video.

In the context of watching something, an often-used word is "gucken" (=to look, to watch) which often is pronounced rather like "kucken".
